What happens when you create a new Python venv in the same location as an existing one?
I recently ran into some issues using Python venvs by accidently recreating a venv in the same location as an existing one.
Steps to reproduce:

Created a venv using Python 3.10.11
Installed numpy 2.1.2 via pip
Recreated the venv in the same location using Python 3.12.7
Attempted to reinstall numpy 2.1.2 via pip, but pip said it is already installed
Ran import numpy as np in the venv

Resulting error (from numpy):
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

It seems like the recreation of the venv messes up something with the numpy installation. As I said above, this was an accident in the first place - I should have created the second venv in a new location. However, I'm curious what might be happening here, and more generally what the consequences of overwriting existing venvs with new ones might be?

Create venv, copy venv, re-create venv, diff copied venv with re-created venv, know answer.

You can only work with one active venv in a terminal session. You can delete the venv you don't want (with it's sub-directories and .cfg file).

pip install numpy --force-reinstall. That should reinstall NumPy, but this time one that is suitable for Python 3.12.

The error shown, however, is an odd one for a simple installation. So you didn't move into the site-packages directory and then ran Python, nor did you download the NumPy source code somewho?

What is your OS? Things may somewhat depend on that, but when you recreate a v-env in the same place, the venv module won't overwrite the symbolic links (at least, it didn't for me), and the python executable/symlink is still 3.10, not 3.12. I could not get 3.12 installed in place of 3.10 when I ran python3.12 -m venv venv.

@9769953 Forcing the reinstall of numpy fixed the issue. I diffed the venv directory before and after this and it seems like the numpy installation consists of different files depending on the Python version (even though the numpy version is the same 2.1.2), so I guess that is probably the issue.
I'm using Windows and didn't touch anything in the venv directory structure between rerunning python -m venv venv.
